# Keep Reactor Kafka Consumers Alive

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, kafka-consumer-api, project-reactor

We are using Reactor Kafka for our Kafka Consumers. We have 5 partitions for a particular topic. So we create 5 consumers for each partition respectively.

Now we have a requirement where the moment a consumer comes it process the number of messages present in the queue and then go off to sleep. The consumer wakes up after a few hours and starts processing messages from the same partition.

The way we've achieved this is by setting MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG to 36_00_000 and CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG to 36_00_000 which will be greater than our wait time. The consumer consumes all the messages in the queue and then a call to Thread.sleep on the consumer sets the consumer to sleep.

Now the problem we're facing is, sometimes we end up having consumers which are alive yet not consuming, even though they are out of thread.sleep. The consumers didn't unsubscribe to partitions either, else I'd known through the logs :-

> `var receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(getConsumerProperties())
>                   .addAssignListener(partitions -> log.info("Partitions Assigned "+ partitions.toString()))
>                   .addRevokeListener(partitions ->  log.info("Partitions Revoked "+ partitions.toString()))
>                   .subscription(Collections.singleton(appConfig.getInitialScanTopicName()));`

Is there a way we can debug why the consumers go zombie? Also somewhere I read pause() and continue(), is it possible to use them with reactor kafka?

Comment: Have you tried setting the heartbeat interval? Also, the docs say explicitly not to block within the poll loop. i.e. don't sleep the thread

Comment: Are you sure that the partitions are not running out of messages?

Comment: @PrashantPandey I kept a track of messages in each partition, and the number of messages consumed by my consumer using Kafka Tool.